# Open a link that contains double quotes by using java

Tags: java, browser

I use the `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("www.google.com").toURI()`in order to open a link on my browser.

On my url link i would like to include double quotes, for example "www.google.com/db/?jql=text%20~\"something here\""

However, if I try to use the double quotes it will not open the browser(without throwing an exception). How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Anestis

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: And what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers do not support **double quote** *(")* symbols in the URL. use `%22` instead of double quote symbol.

If you ever want to use characters that are not supported by the HTTP standards *(such as double quotes)*, use **`%ID`** where **ID** is the *alt code* of the character.

For example:

> %20 - SPACE
>
> %22 - double quotes

[Here is a list of characters + their codes that you can use in HTTP url line.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Also, you can use the URLEncoder.encode() method to encode them automatically for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: for a strange reason it converts %34 to 4  :D